# Mirror vim actions across multiple files (like multi-cursor mode in VS Code)

Tags: vim

I have two files that start with the same multiple line header. What I want is to open both, make changes to the first header and have those changes propagate to the second file. Sort of like how multi-cursor mode in VS Code or Sublime repeats your actions in multiple locations. Is there a quicker way to do this than recording a macro or using a replace command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl+V will allow you get into block visual mode, where you can edit multi lines at the same time.
Otherwise if you want to select same words and edit them together just like VS code or Sublime text, there is a plugin for that：
https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors

Answer (score 0):

You can also use macros to this
for eg: you have multiple buffers open and you want to change the first line in each buffer to: "Created By Me".
You can easily achieve this by usign macros like this:

1. start recording in a macro

> qq

2. enter the next buffer by entering the following command in command mode and
   press enter key

> :bn

3. Now go to the top of the file and enter insert mode by pressing following keys

> ggi

4. Now make your changes

> "Created By Me"

5. press <esc> key
6. save the file

> :w

7. stop macro recording by pressing q
8. Now play the macro for n times (n denotes the no. of files in buffer, suppose 9
   files are there in buffer)

> 9@q